# Silverlight: Problem with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, events

I'm having difficulty with events. I'm building a Windows Phone 7 app.

I have a few classes that implement an editable list box, that can switch into editing mode and let the user add or remove items.

`EditableListBox.xaml` and the code behind is the wrapper around the `ListBox`.

`EditableListBoxController<T>` is the class that controls the behavior. I made it generic for greater type safety, although that means that I need to break it into a separate class instead of implementing the functionality in `EditableListBox.xaml.cs`, which is kind of a pain.

`EditableListItem` is a single item in the list. It wraps the items that are being added or removed, and is responsible for knowing if that item belongs in the list, if the "edit" icon should be displayed, etc.

EditableListBox.xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ListBox x:Name="ContentListBox">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid ManipulationCompleted="Grid_ManipulationCompleted">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Width="96"
                           Height="96"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Visibility="{Binding Editing, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"
                           />

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                               Grid.Column="1" 
                               Foreground="{Binding Enabled, Converter={StaticResource enabledConverter}}" />

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

In the data template, the editing icon binds to `EditableListItem.Editing`:

```
    public bool Editing
    {
        get
        {
            return _parentListController.Editing;
        }
    }
```

`EditableListItem.Editing` binds to `EditableListBoxController<T>.Editing`:

```
    private bool _editing;
    public bool Editing
    {
        get
        {
            return _editing;
        }
        set
        {
            _editing = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Editing");
            refreshItemsSource();
        }
    }
```

`EditableListItem` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so it can update the UI appropriately. It listens to `PropertyChanged` on the parent controller, so it can update `Editing` when it needs to:

```
    private EditableListBoxController<T> _parentListController;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


    public EditableListItem(T item, EditableListBoxController<T> parentListController)
    {
        _parentListController = parentListController;
        _parentListController.PropertyChanged += PropertyChanged;
        _parentListController.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(_parentListBox_PropertyChanged);
        this.ContainedItem = item;
    }

    void _parentListBox_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

The `EditableListItem`'s constructor is called here:

```
    private void refreshItemsSource()
    {
        if (_sectionsSource == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _editableListBox.ContentListBox.ItemsSource = (from section in _sectionsSource
                                                      where Editing || section.Enabled
                                                      select new EditableListItem<T>(section, this)).ToList();
    }
```

For some reason, however, this doesn't work. When I change the controller's `Editing` property, the `PropertyChanged` event handler is null. Thus, the event doesn't get fired. This is odd, because I step through in the debugger and see that the `EditableListItem<T>` is registering its event handler, yet somehow it appears to have been deregistered later?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: one suggestion, in your set {} on a property that is notifying, you should check if the new value == the old value before assigning and raising a change notification. If the values are == they are not really changing, right?

Comment: Right, they're not, but for my app it doesn't really make a difference to the user experience (as far as I can tell.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you are binding to EditableListItem.Editing and no event is being raised to indicate this is changing, only that the underlying property of the `EditableListBoxController` is changing, but this is not being monitored by the `ListBox`

Off the top of my head I would say that you should have `EditableListItem` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Then the `EditableListItem` should wire it self to the PropertyChange event of the `EditableListBoxController`.

When the controller fires the event the `EditableListItem` will handle the event and fire it's own `PropertyChanged' event indicating that the`Editing` property has changed.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do, but it's not working for some reason. (see code above.)